# Shouldn't the graph of $y=1$ be the same as $y=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ because $1=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Shouldn't the graph of $y=1$ be the same as $y=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ because $1=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ ?

So why is it that my calculator said otherwise? And I know that you can't square root a negative number, because it will gave an imaginary number. Is it because the calculator assume that if it there is an undefined value in the equation, the final result will be undefined too? Or is there a proof that I aren't aware of?

Unnecessary comment below:

And if graph of $y=1$ aren't the same as $y=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ just like the calculator said. That would be great, because you don't have to clarify the domain outside the expression. You could just do $y=2x\cdot\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ instead of using a set notation such as $\{x\in| \mathbb{R},x>4\}$

Comment: If you divide something that is undefined by something that is undefined, you get an undefined result.

Comment: So do you think that "two wrongs" make "one right"?

Comment: @Kyky What is undefined at $\frac{\sqrt{x-4}}{\sqrt{x-4}}$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $y=1$ on all real numbers, including $4$, they cannot be the same as you cannot define the other function on the same domain, and for two functions to be the same (formally) their domain has to be the same.

On $\mathbb{C}$ the same holds, as for $x = 4$, the second function is not defined.

If you write these functions down formally you would have to say what there domain of definition is. If you define the first function $y=1$ on the same domain as the second they are the same. So it all depends on your choice of domain, which shows how important it is to keep in mind, that when defining a function you always have to state from where to where it maps, otherwise the definition is uncomplete.
I hope this also clarifies the question in your comment.

Comment: "On C the same holds, as for x=4, the second function is not defined." That just answered my question. I wasn't thinking of that before. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The equation $y=1$ is independent of $x,$ but your quotient of square roots is not. Working within the real numbers, the radical quotient makes sense only when $4-x > 0$ for two reasons: so you do not introduce complex numbers (if $4-x<0$); and so that the denominator is not $0$ (if $x=4$).

Comment: Even if it introduces complex number, shouldn't it cancel itself to become 1? So why is it said undefined? Are imaginary numbers aren't allowed to cancel itself?

Comment: @Sometimesomewhere Why are you asking if you have already accepted an answer? Mmh ...

Comment: @callculus the latter said that if x=4 proves that the graphs aren't the same, therefore my question are answered. But I still don't understand the former

Comment: @Sometimesomewhere What about removable definition gaps?

Comment: @callculus you can't divide 0 with 0 i think

Comment: @Sometimesomewhere Maybe you can google that term. Here is a [link](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/Continuity06.htm)

Comment: @Sometimesomewhere -  Let $r(x)$ represent the radical expression. As Guenterino says, you have to come to grips with the domain of the function $y=r(x).$ If you allow $x$ to be complex, then $y=1$ is equal to $y=r(x)$ for every $x$ except $x=4,$ the value at which $r(x)$ is not defined, because of the division by $0.$ If you restrict the domain to those real $x$ less than $4,$ the graphs will be identical.

Comment: $0/0$ is undefined. If it had a value $t,$ then $0/0=t$ implies that $0=0\cdot t,$ but this equality is satisfied by any real (or complex) $t.$ So, a unique value cannot be assigned to $0/0.$

Answer (score -1):

### No

Your logic is sound in thinking that since $\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}} = 1$, that $y=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ could be equal  to $y=1$, but since your value of $x$ isn't defined, in this case, $y=\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$ is not equal to $y=1$